# Is it correct to say "don't have random food and drink sold in the street"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

"**random**" ("not known or not identified") often refers to a person

> Some random guy gave me a hundred bucks.
>
> You don’t want some random dude telling you how to live your life.

Can "**random**" refer to a thing?

For example, "**don't have random food and drink sold in the street**" when we talk about "**food**" or "**drink**" that we don't know much its origin and whether it's safe or not.

**Note**: Food and drink sold in streets in some developing countries may not be safe and hygienic.

Comment: The _real_ meaning of 'random' is 'happening without a conscious decision', as in 'choosing something at random'. The sense of 'unknown or unspecified', as in 'random guy', is informal. To me, **random street food** would imply that you went to the nearest stall without waiting to check what else was available!

Answer (score 1):

Using **random** like this is informal and slangy, but it can be used to mean "arbitrary", "undistinguished", or "unspecified" in some contexts.

These meanings may come from American hacker culture; the placeholder name [J. Random Hacker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J._Random_Hacker) was in use at MIT as far back as the 1960s, and the ["Jargon File" dictionary of slang](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/) lists a number of definitions for [*random*](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/R/random.html) like

> 2. Assorted; undistinguished. “Who was at the conference?” “Just a bunch of random business types.”

> 6. Arbitrary. “It generates a random name for the scratch file.”

So yes, you can use *random* in the sense you mean, but be aware that it's very informal and slangy, and may not be understood by everyone.

Comment: What you say is true, however, random food and drink does not work for me at all. random numbers, random names, sure.